# changing all occurrences of a string in filenames and their content

Tags: eclipse, replace

I have code of the form:

```
myfile/foo/Foo.java:

    public class Foo() {
         System.out.println("I'm a Foo");
    }
```

in an arbitrarily deep directory tree and I'd like to change all occurrences of "foo" to "bar" , "Foo" to "Bar", etc. in both filenames and content automatically. (I'm happy to do these sequentially, changing the substitution strings each time - there's a limited number of lexical forms).

```
myfile/bar/Bar.java:

    public class Bar() {
         System.out.println("I'm a Bar");
    }
```

I use Eclipse and if there are tools in it that would work. I suspect it's easier to use a UNIX script. If so I would be grateful for an example as my UNIX is rusty and this need not be Java-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not super elegant but you can do it in two steps :

1. Rename files with a native multi file rename utility. I personally prefer KRename it is a GUI tool and available on most linux distributions. this will only rename the file names, but not the content
2. In eclipse you can do a replace strings in multiple files with the Search/Search/Replace command (or just look for the compilation errors and apply a quick fix for all)

Comment: Thanks. Useful start. I can't rely on compilation errors as some of the strings are string constants such as classnames.

Comment: I have found Renamer (http://www.den4b.com/?x=downloads ) for Windows which looks to do the file part of what I want... (presumably equiv to KRename)

Comment: marking as "accepted" as this is a useful answer. I am surprised there are not more utilities for doing the whole lot.

Comment: KRename was very useful